# Delete all the lines from log file older than 10 days

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder and I am trying to delete all the lines greater than 10 days.

Input as below: `error.log`

```
20200122024227-vision.log
20200122024730-vision 20200122024930 Missing 20200122024730-vision.log
20200520210139 Failed :
20200811152053-ibm 20200811152254 Missing
20200812164636-ibm_global 20200812164837 Missing
20200812210311-ibm_global 20200812210512 Missing
20200813080856-ivr 20200813081056 Missing
20200813092556-chat_global 20200813092757 Missing
20200813125528-ibm_global 20200813125728 Missing
20200813163610-acaps_global 20200813163810 Missing
20200813172428-mvs_global 20200813172629 Missing
20200820204216-pos_global 20200820204417 Missing
20200910103742-chatbot_global 20200826103943 Missing
20200913103742-chatbot_global 20200826103943 Missing
20200914103742-chatbot_global 20200826103943 Missing
20200915103742-chatbot_global 20200826103943 Missing
20200916103742-chatbot_global 20200826103943 Missing
```

My output should be:

```
20200910103742-chatbot_global 20200826103943 Missing
20200913103742-chatbot_global 20200826103943 Missing
20200914103742-chatbot_global 20200826103943 Missing
20200915103742-chatbot_global 20200826103943 Missing
20200916103742-chatbot_global 20200826103943 Missing
```

These logs are less than 10 days.

First I need to fetch the timestamp from the line which is `20200916103742` and check whether that is less than retention period or not. If it falls in retention we have to keep otherwise delete.
The parameters that I am passing to my program are current stamp and the retention period as 10 days.

So which means I need logs only for last 10 days and rested to be deleted from the error.log

Code is as below:

```
current_date = sys.argv[1]
retention_period  = sys.argv[2]
old_date = int(current_date ) - int(redention_period*1000000)
path = "abc/log/log_test/"

error_file = path+"error.log"

file = open(error_file)
output = []

for line in file:
    print(line)
    str_log_key = line[0:13]
    log_key = int(str_log_key)

    if log_key in range(old_date, current_date):
        output.append(line)

f.close()
f = open(error_file, 'w')
f.writelines(output)
f.close()
```

And I am getting error as below:

```
if log_key in range(old_date, current_date):
  TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

**Is** there any other better way to code?

Comment: Where did you define `present_date`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that with `present_date` you meant `current_date` then you need to convert it to integer too.

Answer (score 0):

this function might help you:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def del_old():

    limit = "".join(str(date.today() - timedelta(days = 10)).split("-"))

    with open("error.log", "r") as file: 
        data = file.readlines()

    with open("error.log", "w") as file2: 

        for line in data: 
            (int(line.lstrip()[:8]) > int(limit)) and file2.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.I ran the above code and looks like the lines older than 10 days are not deleting. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @Nag Did you call the function??

Comment: Yeah i called. But there is no change in file.

Comment: import os and then can you replace `"error.log"` with `f"{os.getcwd()}//error.log"` ? that might help @Nag

Comment: Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, creating a new file:

```
from datetime import date

errorfile = open(f'error.log', 'r')
errorNew = open(f'error_new.log', 'a+')

current_date = date.today()

for line in errorfile:
    date_line = date(int(line[0:4]), int(line[4:6]), int(line[6:8]))
    diff = (current_date - date_line)
    if diff.days < 10:
        errorNew.write(line)
```